# How to match a string of the form 'word=A B|word=C|word=D E word=E|word=F G'?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to match strings of the form `word=A B|word=C|word=D E word=F|word=G H` using Python's [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The string is in one line. This is the output that I want:

```
word=A B|word=C|word=D E , word=F|word=G H
```

This is my regex till now

```
word=(?:[^word]\w+\s*\w+(\|?:=[^word]*)?)
```

It's an incomplete regex for now, and I have been trying to improve upon it with no desirable output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the entire string, use below regex

```regex
(?:word=[\w |]+(?=word|$))+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NihfWC/1)

If you want to just place comma, considering `|` as delimiter use below regex, with `re.sub()`.

```
\s(?=word=)
```

**Example**

```py
import re
text="word=A B|word=C|word=D E word=F|word=G H"
print(re.sub(r"\s(?=word=)",",",text))
```

**Output**

```
word=A B|word=C|word=D E,word=F|word=G H
```